# Apply a function at group level in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

### Short Version

In `ggplot2`, what do I have to do in order to have a function inside the `x` or `y` of an aesthetic be applied after splitting the `data` (e.g. using `group` or `color`)?

### Long Version

I'm trying to find a way to have `ggplot` apply a function within a group while plotting.

#### Motivating example

Suppose we have a population that all have a hidden value. The rank (and therefore the CDF) of these hidden values is exposed.

```
my_data <- data.table(class = sort(rep(x = c('a','b','c'), times = 3)))

hidden <- c(10, 15,  80,
             0, 50, 100,
             5, 90,  95)

my_data[, rank := ecdf(hidden)(hidden)]
```

I can use the overall CDF to infer the CDF inside the class. I want to then graph each class' CDF against the overall CDF, which helps me to see if the the distribution of the hidden value is consistent between classes.

#### My Best Attempt

After several iterations, I'm surprised this doesn't work. I would think that by setting the group at the highest level aesthetic, the function would be applied in the same way that stats are. Instead, `ecdf(rank)(rank)` is applied to the entire column again, which results in `y` being equal to `x`.

```
ggplot(data = my_data, mapping = aes(color = class)) +
  geom_line(mapping = aes(
    x = rank,
    y = ecdf(rank)(rank)
  ))
```

[image: lines all on top of each other]

Here is an example where a stat is applied at the level of `color`.

```
ggplot(data = data, mapping = aes(color = class)) +
  geom_density(mapping = aes(
    x = rank,
    y = ..scaled..
  ))
```

[image]

#### My Best Workaround

Through the magic of split-apply-combine (here accomplished using `by` from `data.table`), I can add an extra column to my data that accomplishes this.

```
data[, class_rank := ecdf(value)(value), class]
ggplot(data = data, mapping = aes(color = class)) +
  geom_line(mapping = aes(
    x = rank,
    y = class_rank
  ))
```

[image: individual CDFs]

Throwing extra columns onto my data isn't the worst thing, but `ggplot2` does enough awesome stuff already that I feel like this is in there and I just can't find it.

Answer (score 2):

1. aesthetics are mapped to the value returned by the expression on the
   rhs of = applied to data as passed through `data`. Grouping by
   mapping other aesthetics has no effect at this point.
2. grouping affects only operations within plot layers, so the only way of applying a
   function respecting grouping is within a ggplot statistic.
3. good examples of statistics that apply functions are `stat_summary()` and
   `stat_smooth()`.

Consequently I think the only way of achieving what you ask within 'ggplot2' would be to use an aesthetic that doesn't yet exist. Defining a new statistic that summarizes the `x` aesthetic ignoring groups and the `y` aesthetic respecting the grouping should be doable, I think, but is it worth the effort? One can easily pre-process the data within the 'tidyverse' as shown below or with 'data.table' as in your own example...

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

my_data <- data.frame(class = sort(rep(x = c('a','b','c'), times = 3)),
                      hidden = c(10, 15,  80, 0, 50, 100, 5, 90,  95))

my_data %>%
  mutate(rank = ecdf(hidden)(hidden)) %>%
  group_by(class) %>%
  mutate(class_rank = ecdf(hidden)(hidden)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(rank, class_rank, color = class)) +
    geom_line()
```

Comment: In particular, if you are fussy about namespace clutter or adding extra columns, you can do this preprocessing either as shown in a pipe or inside the `data` argument to `ggplot()`.